# PJAX перезагрузка страницы

Tags: javascript, ajax, pjax

Собственно как заставить `PJAX` сделать запрос на сервер и обновить страницу без перезагрузки не нажимая на ссылку. Пробовал следующее

```js
$('a#pjax-reload').trigger('click')
```

Но результата не дало ни какого. Просто выполнялся переход по ссылке. Возможно я где-то не правильно понял суть и ответ на поверхности.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте такой вариант:

```
$('selector').on('click', function() {
    $.pjax({
        container: 'контейнер',
        url: 'url'
    });

   //Ответ к комментарию:
   $(this).off('click');

    return false;
});
```

Тем самым вы удаляете обработчик после его срабатывания.

Либо так:

```
$('selector').on('click', function() {

}).off('click');
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ, возможно вы знаете как поступать когда у меня допустим накапливается несколько обработчиков в контейнере и после второй отправки формы она начинает отправляться больше раз и растет количество отправок в прогресии.

Comment: @Arendach, Изменил ответ.